# How to extend the ticker duration without a race?

Tags: go, synchronization, ping

I'm trying to implement a keepAlive mechanism. The issue is that I don't know how to replace the keep alive ticker ( conn.keepAlive) without a race because `keepAlive()` method always reads from the ticker.

```
//errors not handled for brevity
const interval = 10 * time.Second

type conn struct {
    keepAlive time.Ticker
    conn      net.Conn
    mux       sync.Mutex
}

// replace replaces the underlying connection
func (cn conn) replace(newcn net.Conn) {
    cn.mux.Lock()
    cn.conn = newcn
    // reset the ticker
    cn.keepAlive.Stop
    cn.keepAlive = time.NewTicker(interval)
    cn.mux.Unlock()
}

func (cn conn) keepAlive() {
    for {
        <-cn.keepAlive.C
        cn.mux.Lock()
        cn.conn.Write([]byte("ping"))
        var msg []byte
        cn.conn.Read(msg)
        if string(msg) != "pong" {
            // do some mean stuff
        }
        cn.keepAlive = time.NewTicker(interval)
        cn.mux.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `Ticker` each time you send a keepalive message, and you leave the old one running. You need to stop the old ticker to free up their resources. Also, it's much easier, and less error prone to replace your entire conn struct instead of stopping it and updating each individual field.

Comment: I can't really replace the conn struct because it's being used by other routines/methods. I'm actually trying to abstract `net.Conn` in methods on `conn` that read/write  messages and heals itself (i.e. keep alive and dials a new connection when  keepAlive or a read/write fails).  If I free up `Ticker`, `keepAlive()` will try to write on a closed connection because `replace()` is called when the underlying connection must be replaced.

Comment: You're still replacing the ticker after every message, which will leak memory and resources for running timers.  You're copying mutexes (which is very bad), you have pointers to interfaces (which you should never have), and you're not checking errors. I think you need to reevaluate how you're structuring this code.

Comment: I thought the ticker is garbage collected after it's drained (i.e. reaches the timeout). Stopping a ticker that doesn't tick anymore doesn't make much sense, does it? The errors are not checked to make the code easier to follow. Indeed I net.Conn shouldn't be a pointer. I fixed it now.  I'm actually using a websocket connection in the real code which is a pointer and thus the silly mistake. Why do you say I'm copying mutexes ?

Comment: A ticker will continue to run until you call `Stop()`, it's just blocked on it's channel. The docs say: "Stop the ticker to release associated resources.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement this much more succinctly, is by using a channel as the synchronization mechanism, instead of the mutex:

```
type conn struct {
    sync.Mutex
    conn        net.Conn
    replaceConn chan net.Conn
}

// replace replaces the underlying connection
func (cn *conn) replace(newcn net.Conn) {
    cn.replaceConn <- newcn
}

func (cn *conn) keepAlive() {
    t := time.NewTicker(interval)
    msg := make([]byte, 10)

    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
        case newConn := <-cn.replaceConn:
            cn.Lock()
            cn.conn = newConn
            cn.Unlock()
            continue
        }

        cn.Lock()
        _ = msg
        // do keepalive
        cn.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: not that it would make the answer incorrect but I think you forgot to stop/refresh the ticker too. :)

Comment: @AnthonyHunt, there's no reason to, unless you want the ticket interval to precisely line up with th time you replaced the connection.

Comment: I might be wrong but without any refresh(i.e. not even before the last ``cn.Unlock()``,  the ``interval`` is ignored after the initial one is reached. Thus it locks the connection permanently (sending keepalive messages continuously)

Comment: @AnthonyHunt, the whole point of a Ticker is that it keeps "ticking", sending a tick every interval.

Comment: now I get it... sorry for my ignorance. For some reasons I confused it with `time.After`.

Answer (score -2):

I ended up with the code below. I'm not very happy how it looks like but it works. Basically I wrapped the mux in a channel so that I can do a select on it.

```
const interval = 10 * time.Second

type conn struct {
    keepAlive time.Ticker
    conn      *net.Conn
    mux       sync.Mutex
}

// replace replaces the underlying connection
func (cn conn) replace(newcn *net.Conn) {
    cn.mux.Lock()
    cn.conn = newcn
    // reset the ticker
    cn.keepAlive.Stop
    cn.keepAlive = time.NewTicker(interval)
    cn.mux.Unlock()
}

func (cn conn) keepAlive() {
    lockerFn := func() <-chan struct{} {
        cn.mux.Lock()
        ch = make(chan struct{})
        go func() {
            ch <- struct{}{}
        }()
        return ch
    }
    for {
        locker := lockerFn()
        select {
        case <-cn.keepAlive.C:
            // unlock the locker otherwise we
            // get stuck
            go func() {
                <-locker
                cn.mux.Unlock()
            }()
        case <-locker:
            cn.conn.Write([]byte("ping"))
            var msg []byte
            cn.conn.Read(msg)
            cn.keepAlive = time.NewTicker(interval)
            cn.mux.Unlock()
        }
    }
}
```